# htaccess mod_rewrite - direct specific multi pages to one page and deny access to files with extensions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would need your help to write htaccess file in order to 1) redirect specific pages with urls like below to one page and 2) also deny access to the pages with extension like php.

```
1)
www.example.com/index   --> www.example.com
www.example.com/about   --> www.example.com
www.example.com/contact --> www.example.com

2)
not found

www.example.com/index.php
www.example.com/about.php
www.example.com/contact.php


3)
be found 

www.example.com/index
www.example.com/admin
```

thanks
Ramin

Comment: I am now using below code however, i am directing all urls to index for now which I need to specify and also I can still reach files with php extenstion which I need to show not found                                          RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /dolarfori/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Comment: RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /dolarfori/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(index|about|contact)/?$ / [NC,L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /dolarfori/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks, I think missed to say that i just need the php file extension and any other extension in url shows "not to be found" but instead to find file with file name only. by this code above i am not able to reach any of the files for now because it denies all files with php extension